# xml.etree.ElementTree parse content in kernel

Tags: python, xml, parsing, gzip

I am trying to convert a bunch of .xml.gz files into data frames. Because there are too many files where many of the nodes are not useful for our project, I will not write all the xml files out.

However, to parse xml using `xml.etree.ElementTree`, I need to get the directory of xml file. Is there a way to parse content in the kernel directly?

```
with gzip.open(gz_files[0], 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
xmlparse = Xet.parse(gz_files[1])
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3251
> in run_code
> exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>
> Input In [63] in 
> xmlparse = Xet.parse(gz_files[1])
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py:1229
> in parse
> tree.parse(source, parser)
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py:580
> in parse
> self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
>
> File  ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1,
> column 0

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to parse gzipped file content as following:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import gzip

with gzip.open('file.xml.gz', 'rb') as f:
  xmlparse = ET.parse(f)
  print(xmlparse)
```